# HiveQL queries with SUM or COUNT not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Only simple SELECT queries are actually returning data at the moment. All other queries simply stop processing after showing the following message:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. tez, spark) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Query ID = root_20161004163653_24333e2f-b221-4639-9b6c-69161aa5a41d
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
```

Comment: Hadoop version? Distro? In the cloud, on a multi-node bare-metal cluster, in a sandbox? Running legacy `hive` fact CLI, or `beeline`, or sthg else? What kind of table - EXTERNAL / managed, Text / AVRO / Parquet / ORC?

Comment: Metastore hosted in MySQL, PostgreSQL, derby? Did you check the ZK locks (`show locks`)?

Answer (score 0):

Simple SELECT queries works fine , the reason is they won't trigger Map reduce jobs in background.

Hive-on-MR has been deprecated in Hive 2 releases as the other, more modern and actively developed execution engines have been production-ready for some time. The support may be removed in future 2.X versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases if you want to keep using MR.

Check the [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12300) , you may have to use either spark or Tez as your execution engine or use older version of Hive.